# Magento: Script died after a certain line of code

Tags: magento

I have this product called "Endless Love".
Here is the URL. http://www.eternalflowersmm.com/floral/flower-boxes/endless-love

Problem: When loading thumbnail images, the script dies. If you view source, you'll see the script ends like this.

```
<a rel="lightbox[em_lightbox]" href="
```

This is a fracture of media.phtml.

```
<?php   foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>

            <!-- Debug -->
            <p>
                <pre>
                    <?php 
                        print_r($_image); 
                        echo $_image->getFile();
                        echo '<hr>';
                    ?>      


    </pre>
                </p>
                <!-- \Debug -->

            <a rel="lightbox[em_lightbox]"  
                    href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile()); ?>"
    //              ^--- SCRIPT DIES AT THIS POINT
                    title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>">

                    <img src="<?php echo $this->h

elper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(true)->resize(50,50); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" />

                </a>
        </li>
    <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
```

The script dies at this point.

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile());
```

Main picture is queried this way and it works.

```
<a rel="lightbox[em_lightbox]"  href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image'); ?>"  title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel())?>">
```

This is the screen shot of admin view of that product. http://screencast.com/t/KVgvuvmE9a
These are the URLs for both images, they are accessable.

http://www.eternalflowersmm.com/media/catalog/product/0/1/01218-600-1.jpg
http://www.eternalflowersmm.com/media/catalog/product/0/1/01218-600-2_1.jpg

I already tried setting dev mode to true and show_erros 1 on index.php. No errors are shown up.
Checked errors.log and system.log. Nothing's there.

HELP pls.

Comment: In the scenario that works, what is the code that gets you `$_product`? I'd like to compare that with your problem code, which gets `$this->getProduct()`.

Comment: Something else I'd try in your position is hardcoding the string you expect the href generating code to produce... have you tried that?

Comment: This is how i get $_product. I'll try the hard coding.
<?php
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>

Comment: Have you checked the errors log of your server ?

Comment: yep, check the exception.log When the helper tries to resize/show the image an exception is thrown. I think :)

Comment: Checked the logs. They're logging other unrelated exceptions but nothing about this one.